# QtWebEngine display black block when I called QWidget::winId()

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <qDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
#if 1
    auto btn  = new QPushButton;
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(btn);
    qDebug()<<btn->winId();
#endif
    auto web = new QWebEngineView;
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(web);
    web->load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

That's the whole code.
Windows 10 , Qt 5.5 .

When I turn on the switch, `winId()` would be called, then the QtWebEngine can not work rightly.

What should I do ?

Comment: How is your `gridlayout` configured? Is it a `QGridLayout`?

Comment: yes, it is.  `centralWidget`  contains the  `gridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call winId() until the widget is visible. You could set an eventFilter that is activated on QEvent::Show, for further information see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter